# Can I learn ecma script 6 without getting on es5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I just learned html and CSS and somewhat JavaScript but I really want to know that can I learn es6 standard without practising or knowing es5 your help is appreciated....

Comment: ES5 is essentially included in ES6.

Comment: its like asking can I learn numbers from 1 to 200 without learning numbers from 1 to 100. You can yourself answer to that question. From your question its also clear that you don't have any idea about what they are.

Comment: @GunjanGupta thank for your ans can you just explain in short what they are

Comment: They are various standards of Javascript created over the years. If you want more than that, go to you tube and search for it.

Comment: @GunjanGupta Thank for your information..

Comment: The latest version of ECMAScript is edition 8, aka [*ECMAScript 2017*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/). Beware that if you code only for the most recent version, it may run on only a small subset of hosts. Compilers like [*Babel*](https://babeljs.io) can only do so much to make code backwards compatible. Knowing a history of ECMAScript and javascript is very helpful when writing robust code since the standard doesn't tell you how new or well supported features are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES5 is included in ES6, you can go straight to ES6 without scruples.

[image]

Comment: Or even with scruples, but perhaps without worries.

Comment: Yep, without worries. :D